# Is this possile to see last saved text on notepad when button is cliked

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

**I want to show a message on notepad for next user when he clicks on a button**.

Actually i want is that when a user clicks on button it should

1) open notepad.

2) he should type some message and save

3) when the button is clicked again he should see the last text saved and so on the cycle can run..

for example i clicked on button **notepad opened**.
 I wrote "hello user" and saved it,than i closed that notepad. 
Than when i clicked on button it should show me "hello user" directly if no text is saved than nothing.

Comment: on button click event, you can read the contents from notepad and show the text.

Comment: i have just learnt how to open notepad on button click . i have done my problem by saving file with some name and than opening again but thats not what i want

Comment: @HappyLee how can i do that?? i mean through code.

Comment: @CraigW. System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe"); how can i pass last saved file name but remember that is changing every time i mean on run time its changing

Answer (score 1):

See

```
`system.diagnostics.process`
```

and pass the file name as parameter to notepad.

Comment: how can i pass last file name as parameter?? i mean all the time when some one is saving text the file name is changing

Comment: The bottom line is that you need to know the name of file so notepad can show the content.  The file name can be predictable (for example sequential) or it has to be only file that's get overridden.  You can also use one file and use markers to separate the content and then use regex or loop to fetch the latest entry.  HTH

Comment: how can i use only one file that i overwrite every time and how to use loop to fetch the latest entry.

Comment: That's one option.  Another option is to write the name of the file in datetime format and get the latest one.  The next person will create a new file with a new datetime name....and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is confusing, but think I understand.

Notepad is separate, so you need a temporary file to pass text in and out:

```
private string lastMessage = "";
private string tempFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "MyApp.txt";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(tempFilePath, lastMessage);

    var notepadProcess = new Process();
    notepadProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    notepadProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = tempFilePath;
    notepadProcess.Start();
    notepadProcess.WaitForExit();

    lastMessage = File.ReadAllText(tempFilePath);
    File.Delete(tempFilePath);
}
```